# how can I find out which tabular models are being processed within SSAS?

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

We have many models on our SSAS instance and we made it easy for users to start the model processing (through a bespoke Excel add-in).

Now, a side effect is that there are apparently several Tabular models being processed at the same time.

Is there a way to find which tabular models are currently being processed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool [SSAS Activity Monitor](https://github.com/RichieBzzzt/SSASActivityMonitor/blob/master/Download/SSASActivityMonitor.zip). The nice part about this tool is you can just launch it and in seconds be looking at all activity in SSAS.

You connect to your SSAS instance then use the **Current Queries Panel**. There will be a row for every query. When you process, the `COMMAND_TEXT` will start with `<Batch...`
[image: Batch]

and further in the `COMMAND_TEXT` you'll find the `DatabaseID` and process `Type`.
[image: DatabaseID]

You could also query the DMVs directly. This query from SSMS found it as well, but it's harder to see there:

```sql
select * from $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_SESSIONS;
```

[image: SQL]

But you could put this SQL into Power Query and have it parse and filter down nicely.